# Why is the model not binding properly in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am developing a web app using nodejs, angular, mongo. Having a weird problem. Model is not binding properly from json object.

this is my Schema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name : {type: String},
  imageURL : {type: String, default: '/'},
  created : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('product', productSchema);
```

And I am passing the product using `POST` to my index.js.

```
router.post('/pictures/upload', function (req, res, next) {

  uploading(req, res, function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error Occured!");
      return;
    }
      var product = new productModel(req.body.pName);
      product.imageURL = req.file.path;

      product.update(product);



      res.status(204).end();
  });
```

var `product` only consists of `_id`, `created`, `imageURL`. not the `name` property.

But `console.log(req.body.pName)` prints out `{"_id":"56d80ea79d89091d21ce862d","name":"sunny 2","__v":0,"created":"2016-03-03T10:15:03.020Z","imageURL":"/"}`

Its not getting the `name` property. Why is that???

Please advise.

Comment: First of all, since this is an update you should delete the `_id` that would be present in your `pName` Object.  
`delete req.body.pName._id;`  
Also you should pass a callback to your `update` method to see if there's an error.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the tip. Image uploading is not the issue. It's uploading properly. @SiddharthAjmera

Comment: When `console.log(req.body)` what kinda object you see ? and try save it just as it comes if you dnt wanna change anything `req.body`.

Comment: `{ pName : {"_id":"56d80ea79d89091d21ce862d","name":"sunny 2","__v":0,"created":"2016-03-03T10:15:03.020Z","imageURL":"/"} }`

`pName` itself is a object here. @7urkm3n

Comment: @NishadAhsan When updating it, can you see difference of `created: date` ? Everything looks fine. Check date then update and check it again do you pass the new date ?

Comment: @7urkm3n, no. I am not changing the `date` value.

Comment: @NishadAhsan when u telling, image uploading works properly. Does update the url of image to DB ? also, ist on the file or separately your Model and Controller files..?

Comment: @7urkm3n, I can update the imageURL in db. Yes, controllers and models, routes are in separate files. BTW, Did u see my answer?

Comment: did u try to add - `product.name = req.body.pname.name;`, because u creating instead of object and then updating it. Try ill post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Solution. It wasn't binding properly because content-type was in multipart/form-data. I had to parse the jSON object, like this:

```
var product = new productModel(JSON.parse(req.body.pName));
```

`pName` had the values in a string.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: If pName is a string (which is the case here, for you're reading the `req`) and you do `JSON.parse` on a string, it will bomb :D

Comment: sorry, didn't get you. `pName` is an object but the values are in strings. @AdityaParab

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, You just creating instance of Product object and then updating.

```
var Product = mongoose.model('products');

uploading: function(req, res) {
    // console.log(req.body); find your object
    // in your case it looks req.body.pname
    var product = new Product(req.body.pname);
    product.imageURL = req.file.path;
    product.save(function (err, product) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
             res.status(204).end();

            // it returns json object back - callbcak
            // res.json(product);
        }
    })
},
```

Comment: `req.body.pName.name ` is undefined.

Comment: yr telling `console.log` prints the object perfectly. I have edited the post check that one too.